# Layers render very slowly when importing from sql

Tags: sql-server, qgis-2.6

I am trying to get a handle on importing layers into qgis 2.6 using the "Add MSSQL Spatial Layer" option. I was able to import a layer successfully, but it seems to take a long time to render. Is there a way to handle layers from a database more efficiently? Are there plugins that you would recommend? Also, would it be better to use a Postgres server and add "PostGIS Layers" as opposed to what is being done now, which is adding mssql spatial layers through an Azure DB connection?

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried adding a spatial index to your DB? 
to add a spatial index : [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196.aspx)

After if the vector layer has a important number of elements, you can choose to display your objects depending on the level of zoom:

In layerProperties -> General

Comment: Juls, thanks for your response. Yes, I have already added a spatial index to the DB. Also, the current layer we are working with is not complex at all. Its just a shapefile with 56 elements in it.